# Uvicorn workers: Why does it ends up using only one?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I don't understand how Uvicorn's load balancing works.

Here's a reproduction code:

```py
import time
from fastapi import FastAPI
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import asyncio
import os
import random

app = FastAPI()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class SomeClass():
    def task(self):
        random_time = random.randint(2000, 3000) / 1000
        time.sleep(random_time)
        return f"process id: {os.getpid()}"

@app.get("/test")
async def test():
    instance = SomeClass()
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, instance.task)
    print(result)
    return result
```

I start the uvicorn server with:

`uvicorn --workers 2 main:app`

Then, I try to send parallel requests:

`for i in {1..20}; do curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/test &; done`

**Expectations:**

- ~10 requests are handled by 1st worker
- ~10 requests are handled by 2nd worker
- total time approx. 25 sec

**Reality:**

- 14 requests are handled by 1st worker
- 6 requests are handled by 2nd worker
- total time approx. 35 sec

Output:

```
process id: 56017
process id: 56016
process id: 56017
process id: 56016
process id: 56017
process id: 56016
process id: 56017
process id: 56016
process id: 56017
process id: 56016
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
process id: 56017
```

Could someone explain what's happening? I must be doing something wrong.

Thank you very much!

---

**EDIT:** I've read your remark regarding the fact that time.sleep block the event loop, but I have the same problem when I run the blocking function in an asyncio thread. So, I edited my code and my output to reflect that.

Comment: time.sleep is not async compatible, so its blocking the event loop.  Use asyncio.sleep instead.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I should have given a better example in the first place.
I tried running the blocking function in a thread but it doesn't really solve the issue and I'm still unsure of what's happening behind the scenes.

I edited my question to provide a better example.

Comment: @Chris I read the answer on this other SO thread carefully and learned many things doing so, but the author suggests to use `run_in_executor`, which is what I did in my edited example, and it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Why do you pass max_workers=1 ?

Comment: I try to mimic a situation where the blocking task is not thread safe. I can run 2 processes (--workers 2) though.

Comment: The logs show that, at some point, one of the two workers stops handling requests. So, the total time to treat all requests is greater than what we'd expect. I was expecting both workers to treat approx. the same number of requests, i.e. ~10 requests each.

Comment: I provided my client side's code already, it's the curl command in the for loop.

Comment: I had a look at all the linked answer's examples, and even tried to run them, but they didn't help me with my question.